# Trasform list in tuple in Elixir

Tags: list, tuples, elixir

I have a list like this

```
[%{User: "1"}, %{User: "2"}]
```

After use

```
HTTPoison.request(method, url, body, headers, option)
```

Where headers is

```
\"headers\":[{\"User\":\"1\"},{\"User_2\":\"2\"}]\r\n}
```

I'd like to have a structure like this

```
[{:user, "1"},{:user, "2"},{"content-type", "application/json"}]
```

And add even

```
{"content-type", "application/json"}
```

But I don't understand how can I trasform my data(user) in tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```
for %{User: id} <- [%{User: "1"}, %{User: "2"}], do: {:user, id}
#⇒ [user: "1", user: "2"]
```

Please note, that `[user: "1", user: "2"]` and `[{:user, "1"}, {:user, "2"}]` **are exactly equivalent**. That said, both represent the same list of tuples (of size 2.)

To add a new tuple: just add it to the list:

```
[
  {"content-type", "application/json"} |
  (for %{User: id} <- [%{User: "1"}, %{User: "2"}], do: {:user, id})
]
#⇒ [{"content-type", "application/json"},
#   {:user, "1"},
#   {:user, "2"}]
```

or, to the end (expect performance hits when appending elements to the end of a list, it’s always better to prepend as shown above and `List.reverse/1` afterwards):

```
users = for %{User: id} <- [%{User: "1"}, %{User: "2"}],
        do: {:user, id}
users ++ [{"content-type", "application/json"}]
```

---

To convert maps to respective keyword lists (tuples of size 2), use [`Enum.flat_map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#flat_map/2):

```
[%{foo: "1"}, %{baz: "2"}, %{bix: "3"}]
|> Enum.flat_map(&Map.to_list/1)
#⇒ [foo: "1", baz: "2", bix: "3"]
```

To get keys as strings:

```
[%{foo: "1"}, %{baz: "2"}, %{bix: "3"}]
|> Enum.flat_map(fn map ->
     for {k, v} <- map, do: {Atom.to_string(k), v}
   end)
#⇒ [{"foo", "1"}, {"baz", "2"}, {"bix", "3"}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay. Im new in this language.
Thanks for your hints

Comment: sorry, the map can be `[%{foo: "1"}, %{bar: "2"}, %{baz: "2"}]`, How can I have the same result with for?

Comment: You mean, an input map? And what do you want as an output?

Comment: the same as user.
for example: `[{foo, "1"}, {bar, "2"}, {baz, "2"}, {"content-type", "application/json"}]`

Comment: I don’t get the requirements. Do you want to downcase the keys? Please specify both input and output.

Comment: yep sorry
 the input can be `[%{foo: "1"}, %{baz: "2"}, %{bix: "3"}]` and output like 
`[{foo, "1"}, {baz, "2"}, {bix, "2"}, {"content-type", "application/json"}]`

Comment: http://elixirplayground.com?gist=7791513a57fcd5a50b48046716eaa3a4 why I have the atom now?
`[{:foo, "1"}, {:baz, "2"}, {:bix, "3"}, {"content-type", "application/json"}]
`

Comment: What do you expect to have there? `{foo, "1"}` is _not a correct Elixir_, because `foo` is not anything defined. There always have been atoms. If you want strings, convert. FYI: in `%{foo: 42}` foo is _also an atom_.

Comment: When you want strings, you probably should specify this in the question, instead of showing the expected output with atoms. Updated.

Comment: you are right, But I didn't know that return atoms. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what exactly you want to transform and how.

Suppose you are want to transform `[%{User: "1"}, %{User: "2"}]` into `[{user: "1"},{user: "2"}]`.

```
[%{User: "1"}, %{User: "2"}]
|> Enum.map(fn(item) -> {:user, item[:User]} end)
```

Will produce

```
[user: "1", user: "2"]
```

And the result is equal to `[{:user, "1"},{:user, "2"}]` (keyword list).